# Postgres (or ActiveRecord) - Where a list is completely contained in another list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a 'queue' string field of the form:

```
"6.3, 6.2, 6.1"
```

that is `versions_required` list - any given row may have any set of version numbers.

Then, I have a list such as:

```
versions_supported = "6.3, 6.2, 6.1" # Matches
# or
versions_supported = "6.3, 6.2" # Does not match (no 6.1)
# or
versions_supported = "6.4, 6.2, 6.1" # Does not match (6.4 instead of 6.3)
# or
versions_supported = "6.3, 6.2, 6.1, 5.9" # Matches
```

(This list only changes when I restart my workers)

I need to find all records such that every required version is in the supported versions list; all records such that the list of required versions is contained in the list of supported versions. Here's what I've got now:

```
Delayed::Job.first(10).select{|j| (j[:queue].split(',') - supported_versions).empty?}.first
```

but I really want to do it within the query.

I *can't* change the type of the `versions_required` field (it's got to stay a string) - but I can change the formatting of the lists/strings however I want, including sorting in any particular way, or changing how the version numbers are converted to a string.

The larger context is that I'm making an encoding server using Rails and DelayedJob, and any given job may require multiple different versions of the encoding process. Since I'll have multiple machines doing the work, each of which has it's own list of supported versions, I'm just going to have each machine only pull jobs that only require versions it supports.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL has an array operator just for that.

```
SELECT ARRAY['6.3', '6.2'] @> ARRAY['6.3', '6.2', '6.1']
```

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

If you can't store the fields as arrays in the first place, you can use `string_to_array`:

```
SELECT string_to_array('6.3, 6.2', ', ') @> string_to_array('6.3, 6.2, 6.1');
```

Comment: And if this is Rails4 then its standard ORM understands array columns (mostly).